# PyCharm Remote Debugging Suddenly Slow

Tags: debugging, ssh, pycharm, remote-debugging, interpreter

I'm facing a sudden and frustrating issue with PyCharm's remote debugging. It used to work perfectly fine, but for the past two months, it has become unbearably slow. Even stopping the debug console session takes up to half a minute, which is incredibly slow compared to its previous performance.

I haven't made any notable changes to my PyCharm settings or codebase, so I'm unsure why this slowdown occurred. I've tried researching the problem but couldn't find any recent discussions or known solutions.

One thing that I'm pretty sure is related: when i make a change and quickly press debug it says No such file or directory: '/tmp/zzIx9EFqz9/my_project', looks like it tries to sync it to some tmp path, but then realize that in my settings, i gave it a specific (non-temp) path to sync. but it still do an initial sync with so temp path.

Here are the key details:

- PyCharm version: 2023.1
- Remote debugging using ssh
- Server configuration: Unchanged, with stable network connectivity

Steps I've already taken without success:

1. Restarted PyCharm and the remote Python interpreter.
2. Verified no unrelated performance issues on my local machine or server.
3. Ensured no resource-intensive processes are running simultaneously.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or insights into this problem. Has anyone experienced a similar slowdown in PyCharm's remote debugging? Any troubleshooting steps or tips would be immensely helpful.

Thank you all for your assistance!